# short_open_tags displaying NULL values in while loop

Tags: php, php-shorttags

I have the following code that's supposed to use the oci_fetch_array() function to fill in some arguments for a new link to display on a website, however instead of

> "
>   http://website.com/reporttest.php?type=1&mode=1&dis=MECH&unit=3&rfo=20
>   "

it is outputting

> http://website.com/reporttest.php?type=1&mode=&dis=&unit=3&rfo=20

Notice "Mode" and "Dis" are non-existent. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong in the while loop, but I'm not too familiar with PHP to figure out why exactly this is performing the way it is.

```
<td valign="top" width=12%>
<?
$count = 0;
?>
        <h2>None<br>
        <table border=1 align="center">

<?
while ($count < $TotalB) {
    $row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_NUM);
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= trim($row[1]) ?></td><td><a href="http://website.com/reporttest.php?type=1&mode=<?= urlencode($row[2]) ?>&dis=<?= urlencode(trim($row[1])) ?><?= $endofurl ?>"><?= trim($row[0]) ?></a></td>
    </tr>
<?
    $count = $count + trim($row[0]);
}
?>
        </table>
</td>
```

Output from rows:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => [2] => ) 
Array ( [0] => 20 [1] => ELEC [2] => ) 
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => EPCP [2] => )
Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => EPPG [2] => )
Array ( [0] => 13 [1] => I&C [2] => )
Array ( [0] => 43 [1] => MECH [2] => )
Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => MNTS [2] => )
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => OPS [2] => )
Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => VLVT [2] => )
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => WHSE [2] => )
```

$TotalB defined here:

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_NUM)) {
    if (trim($row[1]) == "") {$TotalB = $row[0];}
    else if (trim($row[1]) == 0) {$Total0 = $row[0];}
    else if (trim($row[1]) == 1) {$Total1 = $row[0];}
    else if (trim($row[1]) == 2) {$Total2 = $row[0];}
    else if (trim($row[1]) == 3) {$Total3 = $row[0];}
    else if (trim($row[1]) == 4) {$Total4 = $row[0];}
    else if (trim($row[1]) == 5) {$Total5 = $row[0];}
    else if (trim($row[1]) == 6) {$Total6 = $row[0];}
}
```

In this case `print $TotalB` outputs `106`.

Comment: You may use print_r($row) just after the oci_fetch_array, to verify your results (from SQL request). To determine if it's an sql pb or a php pb.

Comment: I just verified $row is the correct value, so it is not a sql problem.

Comment: please do a `print_r($row)` and post the contents

Comment: the output is the following:

Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 20 [1] => ELEC [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => EPCP [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => EPPG [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 13 [1] => I&C [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 43 [1] => MECH [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => MNTS [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => OPS [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => VLVT [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => WHSE [2] => )

Comment: ( [0] => 43 [1] => MECH [2] => )
As you can see, [2] for MECH entry is empty... So it seems correct PHP but bad datas :)

Comment: Your first link will have empty mode and dis, the following links should have tekst in dis but empty mode (switched). Correct? But Im curious about why you made this complex counter: $count = $count + trim($row[0]);  ?!

Comment: Aha! That makes sense. Now I need to figure out why the tables aren't displaying.. This isn't my code (stuck with updating scripts that were made 5 years ago). From my understanding, since it's a while loop it should be creating a table with each name in the first column with the amount and link in the second column. However when I go to the webpage, the table doesn't show up at all.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/49zTPas.png  This is what's happening. On the left is what it looks like now, on the right is what I want it to look like. I had to make the one on the right in Excel since I can't get it to show up properly on the webpage.

Comment: Where is `$TotalB` defined? It looks like you're getting one row with empty values. My guess is that the loop runs for one iteration, prints the row with empty values, and then increments `$count` to greater than `$TotalB` so the loop ends.

Comment: @Don'tPanic edited original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do away from the inline php with html and also don't forget to close that h2 tag.

```
<?php

$data = array(
    array ( 1, "",""),
    array ( 20, "ELEC", ""),
    Array ( 1, "EPCP", ""),
    Array ( 4, "EPPG", ""),
    Array ( 13, "I&C", ""),
    Array ( 43, "MECH", ""),
    Array ( 15, "MNTS", ""),
    Array ( 1, "OPS", ""),
    Array ( 7, "VLVT", ""),
    Array ( 1, "WHSE", "")
);

//print_r($data);

$endofurl = "#"; //if you don't set this you get a notice because you call this var, i assume it's the unit=3&rfo=20 bit

// mode will be empty because you set mode=$row[2] and that last key is always empty

foreach ($data as $row){
?>
<tr>
    <td><?= trim($row[1]) ?></td><td><a href="http:website.com/reporttest.php?type=1&mode=<?=urlencode($row[2])?>&dis=<?=urlencode(trim($row[1]))?><?=$endofurl?>"><?=trim($row[0])?></a></td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>
```

or you can try without the inline php like so

```
<?php
while ($count < $TotalB) {
    $row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_NUM);
    print'
    <tr>
        <td>'.trim($row[1]).'</td><td><a href="http:website.com/reporttest.php?type=1&mode='.urlencode($row[2]).'&dis='.urlencode(trim($row[1])) . $endofurl.'">'.trim($row[0]).'</a></td>
    </tr>';

    $count = $count + trim($row[0]);
}
print '
    </table>
</td>';

?>
```

Comment: I'll try this after my lunch break and get back to you!

Comment: This works spectacularly, thank you for making updating 5 year old scripts a lot simpler!